# What can cause headset bearings to become loose quickly?

Tags: headset

On a new-ish CX bike (about 1 year old), I frequently need to adjust/tighten the headset bearings (semi-integrated ahead type).

After a few rides, they become loose which is noticeable by a "shuddering" feeling when using the front disk brake. Additionally, there is noticeable play in the bearings when I pull the brakes and move the bike back and forward.

What can cause the headset to become loose that quickly? What can I do about it? I already tightened all screws on the stem to spec (the label says "all max 8Nm") after tightening the adjustment screw, is there anything else I can try without specialized tools or replacing the headset?

Comment: Does the fork have a carbon fiber steerer?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus AFAIK, it is has carbon blades and an aluminium steerer tube.

Comment: Tightening the screws on the stem is not enough. There are videos on YouTube and on Parktools' site that show how to adjust the headset properly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK5u5ioZU8M

Comment: If steerer is CF I would advise using *carbon assembly compound* which helps grip the composite.

Comment: If it were an old school theadded headset, I'd put low strength locktite on the upper threads to help the top cone stay still.  And then I'd tighten down the locknut onto the top cone firmly.     (commenting for completeness)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few months ago, I finally found the most likely reason for my problem: Instead of a star nut, this bike uses an expander plug under the top cap. This plug extends about 4mm above the end of the steerer tube, like this:

```
######### 
|#######|
|#######|
|#######|
```

Where the `#` represent the plug, and the `|` is the steerer tube. I had the stem at the topmost position, and I suspect that it not only gripped the tube, but also the compression plug. Which in turn was loosened by vibration and the stem moved upwards with it, loosening the bearings.

I have since moved a spacer above the stem so that it does not touch the plug; this seems to have fixed the problem. The lower handlebar position is fine with me, and my problem hat not re-occurred for the last months despite riding some rough-ish trails.

Comment: But as others in the comments have pointed out: If the stem is clamped down with the correct torque it shouldn’t shift even if you remove the cap and nut. I think some weight weenies even do this for maximum weight savings. Insufficient space between cap and tube can be a problem but if you are able to tighten it far enough to remove play it shouldn’t have been be the culprit in your cause.

Comment: @Michael: The problem is: If the plug is slightly wider than the tube, then I wouldn't even be able to remove the plug as the stem is clamped to the plug instead of fully clamped on the tube. This is the only logical explanation for me; after moving the spacer, I still used the same torque as specified (and as before) so the torque shouldn't be the culprit.

Comment: I'll see if I still have a photo of the plug to make things more clear; otherwise, I'll add it as soon as I disassemble that part of my bike again.

Comment: Ah, yes, that could be an issue. Though the stem’s clamping area is split in the middle with a screw for each half, so at least the bottom half should still clamp to the tube, maybe to avoid precisely this issue.

Comment: All stems do not have the split clamp. Iirc it's recommend that with carbon steerers you use one spacer on top of the stem, probably this is one reason why

Answer (score 1):

It could potentially be a slipping starnut, similar to this: http://forums.roadbikereview.com/components-wrenching/slipping-star-nut-42741.html
Albeit a less severe case since it only seems to happen whilst riding.

Comment: The stem should be clamped on so that it doesn't shift even if you remove the top cap

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this question! I since have found the reason for my trouble, and will post an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

My friend has been riding his second hand bike (fluid frame-aliminium) for over 2 months. Last night he rode it with no issues as like every other time he had rode the bike, which is many times everyday. This includes jumping off gutters and down stairs.

Comment: Welcome to the site  - could you please use [edit] to expand on how this answers OP's question about headset bearings becoming loose quickly ?